# Create index in mongo atlas from github actions pipeline

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, github-actions

In my team we're working with AWS lambdas in node and we need to create indexes in an atlas mongodb. For the CI we have a github actions pipeline and I saw that we could create the indexes from a job of the pipeline by two possible ways:

- Installing mongosh but we need to whitelist the ip of the machine (this would be impossible as this machine is managed by github and the ip can change anytime)
- Using the mongoDB API to create indexes, but I don't see this option here https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/api/data-api-resources/ Do you know if there are options to create indexes via mongodb API?

And there is a third idea:

- To create a lambda that creates the indexes and that is called from the github actions after the deployment.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried the command line client? https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/cli/stable/command/atlas-clusters-indexes-create/

Comment: Is [this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/api-resources-spec/#tag/Rolling-Index) what you are looking for?